# Unable to use SED command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

i want to call a shell scripts which has sed command in it to format the xyz.csv generated by this shell. SED gets unrecognised in this code

Comment: You are using `sed` inside `<<EOF` - what exactly do you want to do? What should the result be? `its output.csv must be used by sed` - I don't follow. Should `output.csv` be used by sed, or `xyz.csv` should be used by `sed` and `ouptut.csv` should contain `sed` execution output?

Comment: Hi , i re framed the question. I just need to use SED command within this shell script itself in order to format the output and get a new formatted CSV

Comment: Then just type the command! You don't post any code, don't post the error message you receive - how can you expect a reasonable response to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `sed` inside `sqlplus`. So add this command after the `EOF` marker. Ans also use the variable for input filename

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="xyz.csv"
sqlplus -s ---sqlconnection-- <<EOF
set pagesize 50000
set linesize 32767
set head on
set underline off
set trimspool on
set colsep '|'
set feedback off
set trims on
set trim on
set wrap off
set newpage none
set trimout on
COLUMN a FORMAT A20
COLUMN b FORMAT A20
COLUMN C FORMAT A20
COLUMN d
COLUMN e FORMAT
SPOOL $FILE
select * from xyz;
SPOOL OFF
SET TERMOUT on
EXIT
EOF
sed 's/ *| */|/g' $FILE >> output.csv
```